# PayPal: Is it possible to let the user see his account balance and make payments to other user from within an app?

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I'm currently working on an Android/iOS app in which the user should be able to make paypal payments to another user (peer2peer) and be able to see his account balance. I already did some research, but couldn't find any satisfying answers.

All I could find is the adaptive payments API for payments, but it's now a limited release product, so it's maybe not the thing I'm looking for.

Has somebody achieved to do this and could provide me with some useful information on which API/SDKs he/she used?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You